# On scrubbing in d3.js timeline -- modify the top xaxis date range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3.js timeline --- and one of the requests is to make the top date range toggle in scale during the scrub.

https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/8/  -- latest example --

so if the scrubber has a date-range of about a year -- show year and month
[image]

but if the scrub has a date range of a month -- show year and month and day
[image]

so I've currently got the tick in full format.

```
  var xAxisTop = d3.axisBottom(xTop)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth)
  .tickFormat(d=>d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d")(d));
```

and its called here for the component

```
  var gXTop = chart.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + 0 + ")")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .call(xAxisTop);
```

and again inside the brush --

```
gXTop.call(xAxisTop);
```

but how do you readjust the code to toggle the format on the range currently in scrub?

---

28th Jan 2020 -- this is the latest example with two ticks -- but I may now need to look into customTickranges -- and options to make this legible.

//in wide mode -- the date in the first axis is sufficient -- e.g. over 20 day spread.
[image]

when the date range is 1 day or less -- I need to break it down so the first axis shows the date -- but the 2nd shows hours -- maybe customticks -- so it shows only 4 hour intervals.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/g89kuoe1/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/8/  - latest

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2y8gkas3/11/  -- adding date in tooltip

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ueL79o/2/ -- very latest

Comment: -- something like this -- https://jsfiddle.net/m6ueL79o/3/  --